# Ineffectual vs. ineffective

Tags: adjectives

Why is that there are different suffixes of adj.?, but it seems to have the same meaning

> Ex. **Ineffective** leadership and **Ineffectual** leadership

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: they are practically synonyms, but see [this discussion on English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35930/ineffectual-vs-ineffective)

> "Ineffective and ineffectual—both—refer to failure. But only ineffectual refers to the kind of failure that happens when the effort was weak, impotent, and/or incompetent. If a team of great lawyers fail to win a vigorously debated case, their efforts have been ineffective but not ineffectual."

From [Oxford online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com)

> **ineffective**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not producing any significant or desired effect.
>
> ‘the legal sanctions against oil spills are virtually ineffective’
>   ‘a weak and ineffective president’
>
> **ineffectual**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1  Not producing any significant or desired effect.
>
> ‘an ineffectual campaign’
>
> More example sentences
>
> Synonyms
>
> 1.1 (of a person) lacking the ability or qualities to fulfil a role or handle a situation.
>
> ‘she was neglectful and ineffectual as a parent’

Comment: Does this apply to all -tive(suffix) vs. -tual(suffix) adjectives? Is this in general?

Comment: @JohnArvin Don't try to generalize meanings of suffixes. There might be some very general connection that will not be helpful in a specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a degree in linguistics, or English for that matter. But, I am well studied in it. It has always been important to me to know the language well. So, if I may offer an answer:

Ineffective and ineffectual have near synonymous meanings. However, one (ineffective) is referring to a thing's general lack of ability. The other refers to a thing's lack of ability in a somewhat particular instance, often times referring to a person who has attempted something, or to the attempt itself. It would seem that there doesn't have to be an attempt on the part of the object to be labeled ineffective, while it does with "ineffectual."

This differential is how I've long understood the comparative phrases, but it seems that some people around the web have answered it the other way around, or differently altogether. So I looked it up in 3 different dictionaries, and the definitions largely support my assumption.

wiktionary
Ineffective: 1: Not having a desired effect 2: Lacking in ability
Ineffectual: 1: Unable or insufficient to produce an effect.

This one was not in-line with how I understand the words, per se. At least at first. However, the word "insufficient" suggests that an attempt was made, but no result came to fruition. The site even listed "futile" as a synonym, which also strongly suggests an attempt. While definition for ineffective did suggest a more general lack of ability.

Merriam Webster
Ineffective: not producing an intended effect
Ineffectual: not producing the proper or intended effect (also futile as a syn)

This supported my position as the definition for ineffectual was more targeted, using the word "THE" and adding "proper."

Dictionary.com
Ineffective: not producing results; not effective
Ineffectual: without satisfactory or decisive effect: (also says futile)

This one was even clearer.

These were the only ones I looked up, simply because they are the 3 most used on the internet. 2 of the 3 clearly supported my assumption, and wiktionary did in a around-about way.

All that being said, the actual differences in modern vernacular are almost completely nonexistent, excepting that the latter is often used by those trying to sound more intelligent (yeah, I said it.) And any disparities between a sentence using one and the other would be subtle at most, but the meanings would likely be nigh indistinguishable.

However, if anyone has input as to where I am failing in my understanding, please feel free to say so.